# What do you call the operator that takes in a number and spit out sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

For example, I want to define an operator $P$ that takes in a value and gives all the partition of that value

i.e. $P(3) = \{\{3\},\{2,1\},\{1,1,1\}\}$

What do I call such an "operator" $P$?

Comment: Well, it's still a function, if that's what you're asking.  I don't know about it having a particular name though.

Comment: You could call it a *set-valued* function. This follows other language such as "vector-valued differential form," etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a function, as noted in the comments. If you want to differentiate between numbers and sets, or at least put emphasis that its image is composed of sets you can say that it is a *"set-valued function"*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a representable functor from Ord to Set?